# can't step into c++ program pixel city in netbeans on ubuntu

Tags: c++, netbeans, debugging, gdb

I'm using NetBeans 6.7 on Ubuntu, and I downloaded a linux port of shamus young's pixel city, 
http://github.com/BryanKadzban/pixelcity/tree/master

but I can't step into it (it compiles and builds and runs fine (a little slow but fine)).  I can step into a c++ sample project in netbeans which seems to mean that gdb is working properly.  What are some of the workarounds / reasons I wouldn't be able to step into a c++ program ?   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you build it with debugger info enabled? For example, if `CCFLAGS` is used to specify compiler flags, does it include the `-g` option? You'll need this before you can use `gdb`.